# Downgrade application to a lower versionCode when user chooses to do so

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, android-update-app

The application I am working on is hosted on a private site(not in any of the app stores).
I want to give users the option to select any version of apk needed for them. There is no problem when updated to a higher version but installing lower version is giving "App Not installed" prompt.

So, I have tried to uninstall the current apk and install the lower version. To implement this, I have tried to download the apk and fire up a service when the user selects a lower version to install. But obviously the service stops right when the app is uninstalled and I cannot continue with installing the lower version.

My question: Is there any workaround to downgrade the app when user needs to?

Details: minSdkVersion:21, targetSdkVersion:30.

Comment: The higher targetSdkVersion should work on lower to. Essentially your app will work between v21 to v30

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no problem with the sdk versions. I need to basically reinstall a lower apk version when user wishes to downgrade the app.